# Verb describing using a Taser on someone?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I've seen 3 versions of the verb used in media:

- **tazing**
- **tasing**
- **tasering**

Which one would be the most correct?

Comment: The verb is "tase", as a simple web search on "taser" could tell you.  It is parallel with "lase" for what a "laser" does, and the earlier "mase" for what a "maser" does, when these devices reach a critical state and emit a burst of radiation.

Comment: I've mostly seen "tase" for the verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all commonly used and acceptable. The OED lists "tase" and "taser" as verbs, but the American variant "taze" also seems to be widespread.

You may want to refer to [this article](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/taser-or-tazer-tazing-or-tasering/) on the subject.

In the end, for such a recently coined word, it's conventional usage that defines correctness, so you're probably good with any of the above three variants, at this point in time.

Comment: *"it's conventional usage that defines correctness"* so in English there are no rules for coining new words?

Comment: @vartec: No rules that are "set in stone", I'd say. As in most other languages, neologisms are most often modelled on existing words that are phonologically or etymologically similar. Failing that, the verb form often just has the identical stem to the noun form.